# IF THEN formula for excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

having a little problem writing right IF/THEN formula. Maybe you could me help with this one.
A1 is "random" number from 0 to >1. B1 can have 5 different meanings, if A1 <0,25; 0,25-0,5; 0.5-0.75; 0.75-1.0 and >1.0 than it will have different name. Question is, how to set B1 to change its name according to "randomly" generated A1 value? For example if A1 is 0,785 than B1 should choose name 4.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean between 0 and 785? Show exact input to your sheet and then desired output. Also mention your excel version.

Comment: Make a list 1 to 4 in one column and associated values in the next column then use vlookup().

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFS(A1<0.25,"One",AND(A1>0.25,A1<0.5),"Two",AND(A1>0.5,A1<0.75),"Three", AND(A1>0.75,A1<1),"Four")
```

Comment: If OP is on Excel-365 then `XLOOKUP()` would be best and clean way.